# Math result is off by powers of ten

Tags: java, integer-division

I just learned how to use static methods. I am trying to calculate the gravity of each planet with this code:

```
/**
 * Calculates the acceleration due to gravity on each planet, and then displays the     info in a nice table and in a text file
 * 
 * @author Ely Eastman
 * @version 14.8.2014
 */
public class GravityV1
{
//method for calulating gravity
public static double [] gravCalc(double [] d, double [] m){
    double[] gravFinal = new double [d.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < d.length; i++){
       gravFinal[i] = ((6.67 * 10E-11) * m[i]) / Math.pow(((d[i] * 1000) / 2) , 2);
    }
    return gravFinal;
}

//method for printing to console
public static void printer(String [] s, double [] d, double [] m, double [] g){
    System.out.println("                        Planetary Data");
    System.out.println("  Planet       Diameter (km)      Mass (kg)      g (m/s^2)  ");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
        System.out.printf("  %-7s%15.0f%17.2E%15.2f\n", s[i], d[i], m[i], g[i]);
    }
}

//method to print to text file
public static void textCreator(){
    //havent gotten to this method yet because it is essentially the same as the one above.
}

//main method
public static void main(String[] args){
    //variables
    double [] planetDiameter = {4880, 12104, 12756, 6794, 142984, 120536, 51118, 49352};
    double [] planetMass = {3.30E23, 4.87E24, 5.97E24, 6.24E23, 1.9E24, 5.68E26, 8.68E25, 1.02E26};
    double [] planetGrav = gravCalc(planetDiameter, planetMass);
    String [] planetNames= {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};
    printer(planetNames, planetDiameter, planetMass, planetGrav);
}
}
```

Everything works fine, except for the gravity column in the table, where everything prints one power of ten higher, except jupiter, which prints three powers of ten lower. image of my output below, since it won't format without putting a lot of spaces in.
[output of program http://postimg.org/image/3oou8o8qt/3ab32a54/](http://postimg.org/image/3oou8o8qt/3ab32a54/)

I know its probably a simple error, but at this stage it just helps to have a second set of eyes look at my code before everything becomes second nature. Thank you so much for your help and patience.

Comment: You should add your current output to the question.

Comment: Why do you multiply by 1000?

Comment: @Nivas Conversion of kilometers to meters.

Answer (score 5):

Two of your constants are off, otherwise your code is fine.

Jupiter's mass looks low compared to the rest of the planets.  [This page](http://nineplanets.org/data1.html) lists it as 1.90e27 kg, not 1.90e24 kg - you're off by a factor of 1,000.

The gravitational constant is off by a factor of `10` because you used `10e-11` instead of `1e-11` for the exponential part of the constant.  You can use one `double` literal for the gravitational constant if you'd like.

```
6.67E-11
```

Comment: SO my code is right! aha. nothing feels better than that.